# Keras model predict train/test shape

Tags: machine-learning, theano, keras

I am training a CNN with Keras but with 30x30 patches from an image. I want to test the network with a full image but I get the following error:

> ValueError: GpuElemwise. Input dimension mis-match. Input 2 (indices
>   start at 0) has shape[1] == 30, but the output's size on that axis is
>   100. Apply node that caused the error: GpuElemwise{Composite{((i0 + i1) - i2)}}[(0, 0)](GpuDimShuffle{0,2,3,1}.0, GpuReshape{4}.0,
>   GpuFromHost.0) Toposort index: 79 Inputs types:
>   [CudaNdarrayType(float32, 4D), CudaNdarrayType(float32, (True, True,
>   True, False)), CudaNdarrayType(float32, 4D)] Inputs shapes: [(10, 100,
>   100, 3), (1, 1, 1, 3), (10, 30, 30, 3)] Inputs strides: [(30000, 100,
>   1, 10000), (0, 0, 0, 1), (2700, 90, 3, 1)] Inputs values: ['not
>   shown', CudaNdarray([[[[ 0.01060364  0.00988821  0.00741314]]]]), 'not
>   shown'] Outputs clients:
>   [[GpuCAReduce{pre=sqr,red=add}{0,1,1,1}(GpuElemwise{Composite{((i0 +
>   i1) - i2)}}[(0, 0)].0)]]

This is my model.predict:

```
predict_image = model.predict(np.array([test_images[1]]), batch_size=1)[0]
```

It's seems like the issue is that the input size cannot be anything other than 30x30 but the first input shape for the first layer of my network is none, none, 3.

```
model.add(Convolution2D(n1, f1, f1, border_mode='same', input_shape=(None, None, 3), activation='relu'))
```

Is it simply not possible to test an image with different dimensions to the ones I trained with?

Answer (score 1):

As fchollet himself described [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1920), you should be able to define the input as so:

```
input_shape=(1, None, None)
```

However this will fail if you have layers that use the Flatten operation.

This suggests that you should be able to accomplish your goal with a fully convolutional NN.